# how to get React chartjs to resize back down with window

Tags: css, reactjs, chart.js

I have this code, which, for some reason, will grow when I resize a window, but not shrink. I was wondering how to remedy this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-example-1nur4

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import LineDemo from "./LineDemo";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <table style={{ width: "100vw", borderCollapse: "collapse" }}>
      <tbody>
        {Array.from({ length: 4 }, el => "foo")
          .concat(<LineDemo />)
          .map(el => (
            <td style={{ border: "solid" }}>{el}</td>
          ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a detailed look at https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html. The [Important Note](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html#important-note) section mentions how responsiveness can be achieved. It states that

> Chart.js uses its parent container to update the canvas render and display sizes. However, this method requires the container to be relatively positioned and dedicated to the chart canvas only. Responsiveness can then be achieved by setting relative values for the container size.

In your case, the parent container for the line chart is the `<div>` element. The `render` function of `LineDemo` component in `LineDemo.js` file then can be modified to look like:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative", margin: "auto", width: "80vw" }}>
      <h2>Line Example</h2>
      <Line ref="chart" data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-example-hzygw

Comment: For future devs, that documentation page moved here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html

Comment: Thank you, @myahl! I have updated the answer with the new page links.

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me was to add chart container a width style:

```
<div style={{width: '99%'}}>
    <Bar options={options} data={data} />
</div>
```

However if I set width 100% it won't work lol

Comment: Very weird, but solved it for me too.

Comment: life saver, spent 2 hours on this.

Comment: i created an account just to let you know this answer resolved about 3 hours of trial. nothing else seemed to work. thank you. ive been googling nonstop, asked chat gpt. nothing did it. but this did

Answer (score 1):

another solution that works, for anyone reading in 2023 is this:

```
canvas {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```